# cargar varias funciones en evento onload

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

Tengo 3 funciones que quiero que se carguen a la vez cuando se inicie la pagina, que esta en una misma vista. Las funciones ejecutan listas que se cargan cada una en diferentes Pestañas, las funciones ejecutándolas una por una cargan perfectamente y con los datos requeridos, pero si trato de poner las 3 a la vez no funciona. Ya he probado muchas maneras y aun no logro que funcione, y poniendo todas las funciones dentro del window.onload me carga solo la ultima, espero puedan ayudarme

```js
<script>
window.onload = cargarFunciones;
function cargarFunciones() {
    function Consultas();
    function Permisos();
    function Recetas();
}

function Consultas() {
    //Aca viene codigo
}

function Permisos() {
    //Aca viene codigo
}

function Recetas(){
    //Aca viene codigo
}      


</script>
```

```html
<div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
<a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-hc-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-hc" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-hc" aria-selected="true">Historia Clinica</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-consultas-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-consultas" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-consultas" aria-selected="false">Consultas</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-permisos-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-permisos" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-permisos" aria-selected="false">Permisos</a>
<a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-recetas-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-recetas" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-recetas" aria-selected="false">Recetas</a>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-consultas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-consultas-tab">  
    <br />
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>                               
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fechaConsulta)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Ver
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbDatos">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-permisos" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-permisos-tab">            <br />
    <table class="table">
        <thead class="thead-light">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fechaConsulta)
                </th>
                <th>
                    Ver
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="tbDatos1">
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-recetas" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-recetas-tab">        
<br />
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-light">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.fechaConsulta)
            </th>
            <th>
                Ver
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tbDatos2">
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: quita los `function` que están dentro de `function cargarFunciones()`, esa sintaxis está mal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reemplaza esto:

```
function cargarFunciones() {
    function Consultas();
    function Permisos();
    function Recetas();
}
```

Por esto:

```
function cargarFunciones() {
    Consultas();
    Permisos();
    Recetas();
}
```

Comment: Gracias ahora ya funciono

Comment: un gusto colaborar con la comunidad. :D